# Not able to Scroll using selenium WebDriver and Javascript Executor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to find out the 5th element in the list and click on it.
**List of all the rooms stored :**

```
@FindBy(xpath="//p[@class='css-6v9gpl-Text eczcs4p0']")  
    List<WebElement> placeListings;
```

**Code:**

```
public void clickon5thHouse()
    {
    Web4 = placeListings.get(4);   // **This is a list of all the webelements in <div> tag | I am picking 4th element from the list and trying to click on it** 
        
        int x = Web4.getLocation().getX(); 
        int y = Web4.getLocation().getY();

        //scroll to x y 
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       WebDriverWait wait;
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Web4);
      //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);");
      js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(" +x +", " +y +")");        
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Web4));
    Web4.click();
        //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Web4);        
    }
```

**Url for Website**
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/?q=London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home

1. Using Chrome Browser.
2. Tried to use all possible scroll methods , u can check the commented code.
3. for all the scroll command its just scrolling till the same point in website , i am not sure i am missing anything.
   [Scrollbar is reaching till this point for all the scroll commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4GF4.jpg)

**Error Logs:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <p size="6" class="css-6v9gpl-Text eczcs4p0">...</p> is not clickable at point (845, 13).    
Other element would receive the click: <a data-testid="listing-details-link" href="/for-sale/details/58485081/" class="e2uk8e4 css-15tydk8-StyledLink-Link-FullCardLink e33dvwd0">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to take care :

1. There's a **cookie button**, I am selecting `Accept all cookies` (If you do not interact with **Cookie button**) you would not be able to `scroll down`.
2. Make use of `JavascriptExecutor` and `Actions class`

**Sample code :**

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/?q=London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class$='ui-cookie-accept-all-medium-large']"))).click();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 250)");
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
List<WebElement> allImgs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[data-testid='listing-details-image-link'] img"));
ArrayList<WebElement> allPrices = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class*='CardHeader'] p"));
System.out.println(allImgs.size() + "and " + allPrices.size());
int i = 0;
for(WebElement e : allImgs) {
    a.moveToElement(e).build().perform();
    System.out.println(allPrices.get(i).getText());
    i++;
}
```

**Output :**

```
25and 32
£2,140,000
Offers in region of
£525,000
£650,000
£480,000
£270,000
Guide price
£750,000
£1,260,000
£475,000
£695,000
£450,000
£795,000
£335,000
£849,950
Offers over
£650,000
Offers over
£725,000
Guide price
£430,000
Guide price
£300,000
£520,000
£1,500,000
PASSED: testSO

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

**Update 2 :**

```
for(WebElement e : allImgs) {
    a.moveToElement(e).build().perform();
    System.out.println(allPrices.get(i).getText());
        if(i == 5) {
            e.click();
            break;
        }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey , i tried to use all the above codes but still getting the below error    ```org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <p size="6" class="css-6v9gpl-Text eczcs4p0">...</p> is not clickable at point (526, 551). Other element would receive the click: <a data-testid="listing-details-link" href="/for-sale/details/58064451/" class="e2uk8e4 css-15tydk8-StyledLink-Link-FullCardLink e33dvwd0">...</a>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101) ```

Comment: What is the error ? and which one you used ?

Comment: Are you launching driver in full screen ? is it headless ?

Comment: for all the scroll command its just scrolling till the same point in website

Comment: May be I can have a look.. but give me sometime

Comment: Thanks @Cruisepandey , I have added error log as well , please let me know if u have any other query trying to put my code in github

Comment: @Jyoti ElementClickInterceptedException is displaying coz you r trying to click on the <p> just try to click on different element

Comment: i think yes correct but i am thinking how to get that hyperlink and click as its dynamic  //p[@class='css-6v9gpl-Text eczcs4p0']/parent::div/parent::div//following-sibling::a - This is taking all 25 results

Comment: @Jyoti : I have changed the entire answer above, it works on my local and scrape all the elements price. Let me know if you have any more concerns.

Comment: Thanks for ur effort. It's working but how to click on 5th element.

Comment: You want to click or extract the text ? simply whatever it is, when you can put a if clause there with if (i == 5 ) { click on the element and break from the loop }

Comment: Ok sure i will try this and will update here .. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me know for any concerns you have regarding this. Don't forget to accept this answer if it is/was helpful to you. Simply click on check mark which is near by voting button

Comment: Check out the updated 2 code, I have made changes

Answer (score 0):

**Just check with the below line of code, I hope the below code will help**

```
driver.get(" https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/? 
q=London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home");
    
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(((//*[@data-testid='search-result'])[5])/div/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::a)"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript
("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    
element.click();
 
edit it as per your requirement
```

Comment: Hi Manish , Thanks for taking time to answer , i have updated my question as well , i have to click on the fifth element from the list.  WebElement is dynamic , new to stackoverflow , please ignore silly mistakes

Comment: @Jyoti you can check the XPath in the answer this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer

```
import com.zoopla.qa.base.Base;

public class propertyListing extends Base {

    static int Web4;
    @FindBy(xpath="//p[@class='css-6v9gpl-Text eczcs4p0']")
    List<WebElement> placeListings;
    List<Integer> sortedPlaceListings = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public propertyListing() throws IOException {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    public int getpropertyListing()
    {    
        for(WebElement e: placeListings)
        {   
            String textList = e.getText().substring(1);
            String changedText = textList.replaceAll(",", "");
            if(changedText != "POA")
            {
            sortedPlaceListings.add(Integer.parseInt(changedText));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(sortedPlaceListings , Collections.reverseOrder()); 
        for(Integer s: sortedPlaceListings)
            System.out.println(s);
        return sortedPlaceListings.size();
    }
    public void clickon5thHouse()
    {
        Web4 = sortedPlaceListings.get(4);
         NumberFormat formatter=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);  
         formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
         String currency=formatter.format(Web4); 
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'"+currency+"')]//parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::a"));
       WebDriverWait wait;
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    element.click();     
    }   

}
```

my Testng Class

```
    @Test
    public void verifyHomeListings()
    {
        int countOfRooms = property.getpropertyListing();
        Assert.assertEquals(25, countOfRooms);
        property.clickon5thHouse();
    }
```